# Carriage return count outputs as space count

Tags: c

Goal of the program is to count the number of character types from an input of 10 characters. But the problem is that I cannot figure out why the carriage return count is always counted as space count from my inputs when I run the code. I first used the `scanf()` function for input. Then I used the `fgets()`, and finally `getchar()` but just could not figure it out.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main() {
    char c;
    int count_alph, count_spaces, count_creturns, count_digit, count_other;

    count_alph = 0;
    count_spaces = 0;
    count_creturns = 0;
    count_digit = 0;
    count_other = 0;

    printf("Enter input character: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        c = getchar();
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            count_alph++;
        } else if (c == '\r') {
            count_creturns++;
        } else if (isspace(c) && c!='\r') {
            count_spaces++;
        } else if (isdigit(c)) {
            count_digit++;
        }  else{
            count_other++;
        }
    }

    printf("Number of English letters: %d\n", count_alph);
    printf("Number of Spaces: %d\n", count_spaces);
    printf("Number of Carriage returns: %d\n", count_creturns);
    printf("Number of Numerical characters: %d\n", count_digit);
    printf("Number of other characters: %d\n", count_other);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: if you don't want it to count, then you'll have to just add on a check that it _is_ a space, but not a carriage return: `if (isspace(c) && c != '\r')`

Comment: So I tried implementing your code but problem still persist.

Comment: You're going to have to give me a bit more to work with than just that. Post your updated code in an edit to your question

Comment: You can check the updated code now

Comment: Are you sure they're carriage returns, and not line feeds? (`\n`) or both (`\r\n` on Windows)

Comment: Somehow when I replace \r with \n, the output finally is correct. But I read in a book called "The C Programming Language" by Brian W. Kernighan &  Dennis M. Ritchie that \r is a carriage return. I'm using Windows btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [that \r is a carriage return.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76020254/carriage-return-count-outputs-as-space-count#comment134075458_76020254)

Yes, `'\r'` is a *carriage return* character.

Yet OP's system generates a *line feed* `'\n'` when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed<sup>*1</sup>.

To count <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystrokes:

```
    //} else if (c == '\r') {
    } else if (c == '\n') {
```

---

As `getchar()` returns an `int` with 257 different values, save the result in an `int`.

```
// char c;
int c;
```

---

<sup>*1</sup> At a lower level, <kbd>Enter</kbd> may generate the pair `'\r'`, `'\n'`, and `stdin`, in *text mode*, converts that pair to `'\n'`, and gives that to `getchar()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. In addition, the reason for the carriage return counted with the space was because of the  `isspace()` function which calls white space characters(blank, tab, new-line, carriage return, etc.).